# Build command failed. OR make.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, build.gradle

I am using native code in the android project seems the last 1.5 years. but today suddenly android studio shows below error.

> Build command failed. Error while executing process
>   D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments
>   {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Android_Project\CLONE\xyz\app\src\abc\jni\Android.mk
>   APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-16
>   NDK_OUT=D:/Android_Project/CLONE/Separate_Apps/xyz/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/abc/debug/obj
>   NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\Android_Project\CLONE\Separate_Apps\xyz\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\abc\debug\lib
>   APP_CFLAGS+=-DDEBUG APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false
>   LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>
> '"D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\..\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe"'
>   is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
>   or batch file.

I have tried too many solutions but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After too much research on this issue finally, I got a solution.

> **Step: 1**

Update `build:gradle` version

**USE**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
```

**INSTEAD OF**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

> **Step: 2**

Update Android NDK Location in project Structure

**USE**

```
D:\Android\sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669
```

**INSTEAD OF**

```
D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle
```

Note: [Install and configure the NDK and CMake](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk)

> **Step: 3**

finally, sync project.

Answer (score 0):

deleting this part from build.gradle file works for me:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'tools/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```